# Namer Error using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a text widget so that the user can input data. This is my first GUI, so any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the fourth class in my program I am writing. Whenever I try this, I get an error saying 'name error: userentry is not defined'. Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 16)

class ConejoApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Fur Their Health")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree, PageFour):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Pet Rabbit Health", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="General Care",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Produce List",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Weight Check",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Rabbit-to-Human Years Calculator",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageFour))
        button4.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="General Care", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Produce List", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Is your rabbit at a healthy weight?", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button2.pack()

class PageFour(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Rabbit to Human Years Calculator", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


        label = tk.Label(self, text="Age:", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack()

        userentry = tk.Entry(self)
        userentry.pack()

        btnCalc=ttk.Button(self, text="Calculate")
        btnCalc.pack()
        btnCalc["command"]=self.calculateAge

        label2=tk.Label(self, text= "Here's your rabbit's human age:", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

    def calculateAge(self):
        rabbitage= int(userentry.get())
        age=(rabbitage*8)
        label2["text"]=str(age)


app = ConejoApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that there was no error on the Labels so see what the difference is between declaring the labels and the Entry (all widgets are in the Tkinter namespace).  Also the indent on the def __init__ is off but I assume that is just a paste error.

Comment: Ahh, that helped me out, seems to be working now, but now I'm having other issues, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your import style. If you imported tkinter as `tk` then your entry needs to be `e = tk.Entry()`. If you want it to be just `e = Entry()` import tkinter like this `from tkinter import *`.

**Edit**

Also you have lost of errors in your script. You don't call `self` when you need it and you do when you don't need it!

Here is the working code:

```
class PageFour(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Rabbit to Human Years Calculator", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


        label = tk.Label(self, text="Age:", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack()

        self.userentry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.userentry.pack()

        btnCalc=ttk.Button(self, text="Calculate")
        btnCalc.pack()
        btnCalc["command"]=self.calculateAge

        self.label2=tk.Label(self, text= "Here's your rabbit's human age:", fg="blue", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.label2.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

    def calculateAge(self):
        rabbitage= int(self.userentry.get())
        age=(rabbitage*8)
        self.label2["text"]=str(age)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've added to this but now when I run it, I am getting a 'name error', any suggestions? I can add what I have now above.

Comment: @valentine_sketer I have edited my answer to fix all the problems.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I posted my full code above. I'm a beginner so I really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @valentine_sketer If i fixed your problems please accept my answer!